# Typescript if statement using boolean variable creates different result than if the same boolean expression was placed in the if statement directly

Tags: typescript

See example below. Creating middle variable "isUndefined" vs directly putting the expression inside the if statement.

```
function x() {
    let x: number | undefined;
    const isUndefined = x === undefined;
    if (isUndefined) {
      return;
    }

    const sum = x + 1; // Object is possibly 'undefined'
}
```

```
function x() {
    let x: number | undefined;
    if (x === undefined) {
      return;
    }

    const sum = x + 1; // Success
}
```

Comment: This is a weird example because `x` is definitely `undefined`.  Maybe you want to reproduce with something like `let x = Math.random()<0.5 ? 123 : undefined` where there's an actual chance `x` will not be `undefined`.

Comment: The answer to this is that TypeScript's [control flow analysis](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) is triggered by specific heuristically-selected syntactic structures and is not automatically distributive over all union types.  Before TS4.4 it wasn't possible to "save" a type guard check in a variable like `isUndefined`. This was added in [ms/TS#44730](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/44730), but only if you guard a `const`, but since `x` is a `let` the compiler doesn't try to track it; you could change to [this](//tsplay.dev/mq50Qm).

Comment: I am happy to write up an answer explaining this if you think it addresses your question fully; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How TypeScript can understand this condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75355670/how-typescript-can-understand-this-condition)