# How can TypeScript understand this condition?

Tags: typescript

when assigning a variable of type `unknown` to another variable, we should go through the type checking of the `unknown` variable but how can TypeScript understand this specific condition? looks like it's returning a `boolean` but I think it's more complicated :

```
let first: unknown = 5;
let second: number;

const result = typeof first === 'number';

if(result){
    second = first; // error : Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'number'
}

if(typeof first === 'number'){
    second = first; // no errors
}
```

Comment: What version of TypeScript are you using? I believe your code should work in TypeScript 4.4 or later: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/44730

Comment: This is essentially the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71984763/typescript-if-statement-using-boolean-variable-creates-different-result-than-if

Comment: A vanilla `boolean` doesn't come with type information, whereas using the condition directly (or an explicit [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)) does.

Comment: @Dai I know but thats not the point, I am using TS  Playground

Comment: [Playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAZglgTgZzALggVwHYGsMHsDuGEAvBAKwDcAUKJAiAMa4YAmqGaAtgEYhzVUmGJBDggEaYJFJgAngAcQuKNHgjiGiAHIOPPloEwoACjESpASgDeVCHYj0hLEqsRgKEAPSeIfOLjgIVAAVBRBtTBwCDC0IGAQIPEgAQwQEGABzDGTuUAgwXHyw7V1eOC0qAF8qKiNjOUVlV3VNHS4yrWtbe0dmZ1JYNw9vRMK-AIQqoA)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[TypeScript added support for indirect expression type narrowing in TypeScript 4.4 after PR #44730 was added](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/44730) in June 2021. In the notes introducing this feature, Anders Hejsberg mentions the limitations of this feature (emphasis and formatting mine):

> Narrowing through *indirect-references* occurs **only** when:
>
> - the *conditional-expression* or *discriminant-property* access is declared in a `const` variable declaration with no type annotation, **and**...
> - the reference being narrowed is one-of:
>
>   - a `const` variable **or**
>   - a `readonly` property **or**
>   - a parameter for which there are no assignments in the function body.

In your case your `let first: unknown = 5;` variable's assign cannot be used with this feature because it's a `let` local variable instead of a `const` local.

So if you change the code to use `const first` instead of `let first`, then it works:

```js
const first: unknown = 5;
let second: number;

const result = ( typeof first === 'number' );

if( result ) {
    second = first; // OK!
}

if( typeof first === 'number' ) {
    second = first; // OK!
}
```

[TypeScript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBAMwJYCdYC44FcIGsJgDuEcAvHAKwDcwANgKbxT3gQAmmEWAtgEb0oaoSLDgp6ULLXjkAFHBgBPAA70wCRKlGkdcAORc+AvXACUQpAnnjJ0s3ADewOC7jNWbMprQwqcAPT+cADyANIAhMAAvsDAlvJKqure2roGPPwoJqaOzq7ukJ7kyD5+gSER0cBAA)