# Variable type changes in array method

Tags: typescript

Is this a TypeScript bug or am I missing something? Variable type changes based on whether it's in an array method or not. This causes type issues and the only workaround I can think of is an additional typecast in a function call.

```
const fn = (arg: string) => {}

let variable: undefined | string

if(!variable) {
    variable = 'asd'
}

fn(variable); // Variable type is string

[].map(() => {
    fn(variable) // Variable type is string | undefined
})
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZmGBeGAKAhgJwOYC4bSYCWY2AlMgHwwDeAvgFAMA2AprAG5ZHoBGb+AK5gAJqzglWImAB8CUYqSZE4qAIRdifNhRoMYBmJp79WyGAHJ0EERYaMGCVMe2syAbhgB6LzABq3K4wUACeAA5mRBDyithMANoAugB0ALboYaioFEjUeobwYM6BphQ+-iVsweGR0YQk2LIwwmISYFL2ZEwGQA)

I expect the variable type to change to `string` once it's reassigned in an `if` statement. This result is present in the function scope but the variable type falls back to `string | undefined` in `Array.prototype.map()` method.

Comment: This is because it's in a callback, and TypeScript does not know when the callback is executed (maybe asynchronously?), so it cannot use control flow analysis to determine the `undefined | string` variable is currently a string. (I'm sure there's a duplicate somewhere).

Comment: The proper solution is to declare `const variable: string = …`

Answer (score 0):

In TypeScript, type inference can be affected by control flow analysis you can have a look [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.2#example/control-flow-improvements).
when you initialize a variable with an union type `undefined | string` as you are doing in the example above, and then, check with an `if` statement to narow down the type, TypeScript will use the narowed type within the scope of that control flow statement.
thats why, inside the function scope, the variable is correctly inferred as `string`.

However, when you use the variable inside the `map` method, TypeScript cannot do the same control flow analysis as mentionned in Bergi comment

> This is because it's in a callback, and TypeScript does not know when the callback is executed

therefore, it does not narow down the type and keeps the original union type `string | undefined`.

a similar behavior I faced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75355670/how-can-typescript-understand-this-condition)